# Funcionamiento de un diccionario de una clase que accede a atributos de una clase diferente

Tags: python, python-3.x

He construido un ejemplo mínimo de un código que consiste de dos clases, `Partida` y `Jugador`, las cuales contienen unos atributos que asignan unos valores que declaro en la función `def main()`. La clase `Partida` contiene además una función `def jugar(self)`, la cual contiene una serie de instrucciones (irrelevantes para el caso actual). La función `def main()` ejecuta el juego mediante `juego.jugar()`. El código a continuación:

```
class Jugador:
    def __init__(self, nombre, s, b, x, m):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.s = s[:]
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m

def __str__(self):
    return "Jugador_{}".format(self.nombre)


class Partida:
    def __init__(self, jugadores, sigmas, b, x, m):
        self.jugadores = {
            nombre: Jugador(nombre, sigmas[nombre], b, x, m)
            for nombre in jugadores
        }
    def jugar(self):
      for jugador in self.jugadores:
        print(jugador)

def main():
    jugadores = [1,2,3,4]
    s1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]
    s2 = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    sigmas = {1: s1, 2: s1, 3: s2, 4: s2}
    muestras = [{"b": 0.0, "x": 0.5, "m": 0.02},{"b": 1.0, "x": 0.5, "m": 0.02}]
    muestras = [d for d in muestras for _ in range(1)]


    for mu in range(len(muestras)):
        juego = Partida(
            jugadores,
            sigmas,
            muestras[mu]["b"],
            muestras[mu]["x"],
            muestras[mu]["m"],
        )
        juego.jugar()



main()
```

Me gustaría comprender:

1. en concreto cómo la `class Partida` está accediendo aquí a los atributos del objeto construidos en la `class Jugador`. Si no entiendo mal, la clase Partida construye el atributo `self.jugadores`, el cual es un diccionario con una clave (`nombre`) y un valor `Jugador` que proviene de la clase `class Jugador`. Ahora bien, no comprendo cómo se están almacenando las características de la clase `class Jugador` en el diccionario.
2. cómo acceder la información contenida en el diccionario `self.jugadores`. Estoy intentando acceder de varias maneras los valores `nombre, sigmas[nombre], b, d, x` y no lo consigo. En la función `def.jugar` estoy intentando imprimir estas características para cada uno de los cuatro jugadores y no doy con el mecanismo.

Se aprecian explicaciones didácticas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actualización** La parte inicial de la respuesta (hasta la línea separadora) ya no aplica al estado actual de la pregunta, pues el usuario la editó para corregir estos detalles de nomenclatura. Dejo no obstante la explicación por si fuera útil.

Lo primero aclarar algunos detalles de nomenclatura, que usas incorrectamente.

- Las "variables" que se crean dentro de un objeto por el mecanismo de asignarles un valor, como en `self.s`, `self.x`, etc. se denominan *atributos* del objeto. Típicamente se crean desde el método `__init__()` que se denomina el "constructor". La misión de ese método es crear e inicializar los atributos de objeto.
- No hay herencia en tu código. La herencia es un concepto de Programación Orientada a Objetos (OOP) que se da cuando una clase hereda de otra, por lo que recibe los mismos atributos y métodos que tenía la original. En python esta herencia ocurre cuando en la declaración de la clase pones entre paréntesis el nombre de otra clase. En tu caso las únicas clases que hay son `Jugador` y `Partida` y ninguna de ellas hereda de ninguna otra (ni entre sí).

Por tanto no podemos hablar en este caso de "variables" que se "heredan", sino de "atributos de objeto" que son "accesibles" desde otro objeto.

---

Vamos ahora con tus preguntas:

> 1. en concreto cómo la class Partida está heredando aquí las variables construidas en la class Jugador.

Como se ha dicho `Partida` no hereda. En realidad, tal como está el código, ni siquiera accede a los atributos del `Jugador`, sino que se limita a crear varios jugadores y es el constructor de esos jugadores el que va asignando valores a sus atributos.

Como bien has visto, el constructor de la clase `Partida` crea un diccionario, aquí:

```
    def __init__(self, jugadores, sigmas, b, x, m)
        self.jugadores = {
            nombre: Jugador(nombre, sigmas[nombre], b, x, m)
            for nombre in jugadores
        }
```

El diccionario se crea iterando por el parámetro `jugadores`, que tal como se está usando parece que será una lista de nombres. Así, cada elemento de esa lista da igual a una entrada en el diccionario, cuya clave es el nombre del jugador, y cuyo valor es **un nuevo objeto jugador**, que se crea con la sintaxis `Jugador(parametros)`. Esta sintaxis *instancia* un nuevo objeto y llama a su constructor, pasándole como parámetros el propio objeto recién creado (como primer parámetro `self`) y el resto de parámetros. Esos parámetros los usa el constructor de `Jugador` para asignarlos a los atributos de cada jugador. En este caso cada jugador tiene probablemente un nombre diferente, y un valor de `s` diferente (sacado de `sigmas[nombre]`), pero todos el mismo valor de `b`, `x` y `m` en este caso.

El diccionario no guarda los atributos de los jugadores, sino que guarda **objetos** de tipo jugador. Cada uno de esos objetos tiene sus atributos. Podrías acceder a ellos con la sintaxis `objeto.nombre`, `objeto.s`, etc.

> 2. cómo acceder la información contenida en el diccionario self.jugadores

Iterando por él. Pero ten en cuenta que en python si iteras por un diccionario, como en:

```
 for jugador in self.jugadores:
        print(jugador)
```

estarás iterando en realidad por las claves, por lo que sólo verás los nombres de los jugadores (que es lo que hay en las claves del diccionario). Si en cambio iteras por `self.jugadores.items()`, obtendrás parejas clave-valor:

```
 for nombre, jugador in self.jugadores.items():
        print(nombre, jugador)
```

En este caso la clave es una cadena (el `nombre`) y el valor (`jugador`) sería un *objeto* de tipo `Jugador`. Al tratar de imprimir ese objeto se invocará `jugador.__str__()` para convertirlo en cadena. Tal como tienes definida esa función, imprimirá algo como `Jugador_nombre` por lo que seguirías viendo sólo el nombre.

No obstante puedes acceder a los atributos de ese objeto, usando `jugador.s`, `jugador.x`, etc. Por ejemplo:

```
 for nombre, jugador in self.jugadores.items():
        print("{}: s={}, b={}, x={}, m={}".format(nombre,
                 jugador.s, jugador.b, jugador.x, jugador.m))
```

Comment: gracias @abufalia, me has permitido comprender mejor qué es lo que está ocurriendo aquí. He intentado corregir la terminología para que la pregunta sea más entendible.

Comment: @pyring Correcto, ahora la terminología de la pregunta está impecable. Pero resulta que entonces la primera parte de mi respuesta no se comprende. ¿Mejor la elimino?

Comment: @abufalia, quizá puede ponerse en negrita, notando que esa parte responde a una edición anterior. Sugiero. O si no, borrarlo. Por mi parte la respuesta es excelente en cualquier caso.